# remove orphaned admin notices in backend?

Tags: wordpress, admin, notice

after moving a wordpress site to another domain (and moved DB also) I have some orphaned empty admin notices in backend that are not longer dismissable. If I inspect them, it seems that they are relateted to OTGS. Everything else seems to work.
How can I get rid of them?

Thx, Alex

Updated as requested in the comments:

````
<div class="notice otgs-notice" data-group="default" data-id="" data-nonce="5469b77b3a"><p></p></div>
<div class="notice otgs-notice" data-group="default" data-id="" data-nonce="5469b77b3a"><p></p></div>
<div class="notice otgs-notice" data-group="default" data-id="" data-nonce="5469b77b3a"><p></p></div>
<div class="notice otgs-notice" data-group="default" data-id="" data-nonce="5469b77b3a"><p></p></div>
<div class="notice otgs-notice" data-group="default" data-id="" data-nonce="5469b77b3a"><p></p></div>
<div class="notice otgs-notice" data-group="default" data-id="" data-nonce="5469b77b3a"><p></p></div>
<div class="notice otgs-notice" data-group="default" data-id="" data-nonce="5469b77b3a"><p></p></div>
<div class="notice otgs-notice" data-group="default" data-id="" data-nonce="5469b77b3a"><p></p></div>
<div class="hidden notice notice-warning" id="notice-corrupt-rest-api"><p>Ein oder mehrere WordPress-Plugins versuchten,
    die WordPress REST API aufzurufen, was fehlschlug. Höchstwahrscheinlich hat ein Sicherheits-Plugin oder eine
    Webserver-Konfiguration die REST-API deaktiviert. Bitte stelle sicher, dass die folgenden REST-API-Namensräume
    erreichbar sind, um das jeweilige Plugin ohne Probleme nutzen zu können:</p>
    <ul></ul>
    <p>Was ist die WordPress REST API und wie kann sie aktiviert werden? <a
            href="https://devowl.io/knowledge-base/i-see-only-a-loading-animation-wordpress-rest-api-not-responding/"
            rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">Klicke hier, um mehr darüber zu erfahren</a>.</p></div>
<div class="wf-admin-notice notice notice-error" data-notice-id="74b69a33-4fb6-6504-bd0d-ad8f21a29f6e"><p>The last rules
    update for the Wordfence Web Application Firewall was unsuccessful. The last successful update check was 18. July
    2023 6:37, so this site may be missing new rules added since then. You may wait for the next automatic attempt or
    try to <a
            href="https://mydomain.xyz/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WordfenceWAF&amp;subpage=waf_options#waf-rules-next-update">Manually
        Update</a> by clicking the "Manually Refresh Rules" button below the Rules list.</p>
    <p><a class="wf-btn wf-btn-default wf-btn-sm wf-dismiss-link" href="#"
          onclick="wordfenceExt.dismissAdminNotice('74b69a33-4fb6-6504-bd0d-ad8f21a29f6e'); return false;"
          role="button">Dismiss</a></p></div>```


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR1rq.png
````

Comment: Is this plugin installed and activated?

Comment: If not try installing. It might solve the problem.

Comment: Yes it is installed and activated. It's part of WPML translation plugin. After migration there were "Your license is not valid because of the wrong domain" errors in this notices, I think. After licening the new domain (where I moved the website to) the plugin is working, but this empty notices are still shown. Are they in the DB somewhere? Can't find them...

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cookies of the browser you are using? Or did you try another browser?

Comment: Sure. Every admin sees this, it is coming from WP.
Where are that notices stored?

Comment: Notices are not stored anywhere. They are generated by php or javascript.

Comment: You could do this in php with the `admin_notices` action hook. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/

Comment: And you can add them with Javascript.

Comment: Whether they get data from a database or not, you cannot tell by just looking at them.

Comment: You should dive into the source code or get support with the plugin’s team.

Comment: It would help if you would provide the html of the notices (all of them).

Comment: post updated with notice markup